# Using C# to Retrieve a MongoDB Document and Select One Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm using C# in ASP.NET Core to retrieve a random document from a MongoDB Atlas collection, extract a specific field ("name") and add it to a web service response.

Since this is a first for me, I've researched several solutions, most of which were suggested on these forums, but the field isn't being retrieved.

Here's what's going on.

(Please note that the database's details have been replaced for the purpose of this post.)

1) In a method created to extract the field, I retrieve a random document before defining a projection and returning the result.

```
var client = new MongoClient("CLIENT");
var database = client.GetDatabase("DATABASE");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("COLLECTION");

var document = new BsonDocument(collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).FirstOrDefault());
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Exclude("_id");
var result = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(document).Project(projection).ToString();

return result.name;
```

However, the result was the following.

> { "city":"find({ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5c4f2f7b9914ed3a4b8aa075\"),
>   \"id\" : 3698105, \"coord\" : { \"lon\" : -80.162497999999999, \"lat\"
>   : -5.0925000000000002 }, \"country\" : \"PE\", \"geoname\" : { \"cl\"
>   : \"P\", \"code\" : \"PPL\", \"parent\" : 3693525 }, \"name\" :
>   \"Chulucanas\", \"stat\" : { \"level\" : 1.0, \"population\" : 68835
>   }, \"zoom\" : 9 }, { \"name\" : 1, \"_id\" : 0 }

2) I therefore attempted to work around this. I omitted the projection and tried to convert the document to JSON, map it to a data model and select the required string.

Data Model

```
public class Document
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string coord { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string geoname { get; set; }
    public string langs { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string stat { get; set; }
    public string stations { get; set; }
    public int zoom { get; set; }
}
```

Method

```
var client = new MongoClient("CLIENT");
var database = client.GetDatabase("DATABASE");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("COLLECTION");

var document = new BsonDocument(collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).FirstOrDefault()).ToJson();
Document result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(document);

return result.name;
```

The result was a blank screen and a Newtonsoft.Json>JsonReaderException.

To debug this, I replaced

```
return result.name
```

with

```
return document;
```

and commented out the following line.

```
Document result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(document);
```

And again the result was similar.

> "city":"{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5c4f2f839914ed3a4b8aa95f\"), \"id\" :
>   4900579, \"coord\" : { \"lon\" : -89.058159000000003, \"lat\" :
>   42.320019000000002 }, \"country\" : \"US\", \"geoname\" : { \"cl\" : \"P\", \"code\" : \"PPL\", \"parent\" : 4916845 }, \"langs\" : [{
>   \"link\" : \"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loves_Park%2C_Illinois\" },
>   { \"post\" : \"61111\" }], \"name\" : \"Loves Park\", \"stat\" : {
>   \"level\" : 1.0, \"population\" : 23996 }, \"stations\" : [{ \"id\" :
>   974, \"dist\" : 43, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 1005, \"dist\" : 13,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 2989, \"dist\" : 33, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" :
>   3010, \"dist\" : 24, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 9277, \"dist\" : 35,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 27762, \"dist\" : 16, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\"
>   : 29682, \"dist\" : 49, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 30211, \"dist\" : 45,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 31051, \"dist\" : 42, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\"
>   : 31756, \"dist\" : 15, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 32614, \"dist\" : 49,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 32643, \"dist\" : 47, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\"
>   : 33291, \"dist\" : 12, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 33712, \"dist\" : 36,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 33902, \"dist\" : 38, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\"
>   : 33980, \"dist\" : 42, \"kf\" : 1 }, { \"id\" : 34925, \"dist\" : 10,
>   \"kf\" : 1 }], \"zoom\" : 12 }

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first attempt (dynamic approach) you mix the Linq version, than use the result with the mixed `.Find` version. You can go full Linq approach>

```
private string GetName()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("WorldCities");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("cities");

    return collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).First().GetValue("name").ToString();
}
```

Or full `.Find` approach>

```
private string GetName()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("WorldCities");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("cities");

    var result = collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty)
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Exclude("_id")).First().ToString();

    return result;
    // { "name" : "les Escaldes" }
}
```

Comment: No problem. For the Deserialize approach, the `Document`'s structure is not the same as in the database. Also you could deserialize with the bson engine, and use `GetCollection<Document>`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to sort the list using above method.

Comment: You can add a `SortBy... ` after the `Find(...)` to define your ordering requirements.

Comment: Thanks @ntohl. Working perfect.

Comment: There is anyway to pick the values between two number i.e select * from t1 where cl_name between 1 and 10?

Comment: Instead of `FilterDefinition.Empty` you can define your "where" clause.

Comment: But my model is bsondocument dynamic output. So i am not sure how to add where clause. Can you provide some reference please

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/ here you can `builder.Gt("cl_name", 1) & ...` at the example.