# How can I read just one field in MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im trying to read just one field from the MongoDB with a given ID, but its giving me all the object... How can I do it ? What should I do? I tried with this repository but its returning me all the object

Here is my class:

```
public class Hall
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<string> Surveys { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my repository with the connection to Mongo:

```
public Task<List<Hall>> ReadSurveysHall(string hallId)
{
  var filter = Builders<Hall>.Filter.(x => x.Id, hallId);
  return _mongoManager.Find(filter, MongoConstants.HallCollection);
}
```

I just want it to give me just the list of Survey's string.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I know what is `_mongoManager` type?

Comment: I think your question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437050/using-c-sharp-to-retrieve-a-mongodb-document-and-select-one-field

Comment: @YongShun its the interface with mongo connection

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Thank you for your anwer, but I need a solution with the Builder

Comment: What is `MongoConstants.HallCollection`? Is it a string constant? Is `_mongoManager` of type `IMongoCollection<Hall>` or something else?

Comment: Hello @Markus , MongoConstants.HallCollection it is, indeed, a string constant for the collection of the Mongo  and _mongoManager its the interface with mongo connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return only the list of surveys, you can change your method like this:

```
public async Task<List<string>> ReadSurveysHall(string hallId)
{
  var filter = Builders<Hall>.Filter.(x => x.Id, hallId);
  var halls = await _mongoManager.Find(filter, MongoConstants.HallCollection);
  var hall = halls.FirstOrDefault();
  if (hall == null)
    return new List<string>();
  return hall.Surveys;
}
```

You can further optimize this by using a projection so that MongoDB only delivers the data that you are interested in, e.g.:

```
var projection = Builders<Hall>.Projection.Exclude(x => x.Id).Include(x => x.Surveys);
var options = new FindOptions<Hall, Hall>() 
{
  Projection = projection,
};
```

How you use that projection depends on the capabilities of `_mongoManager`. Take a look at the `Find` methods and check whether any of these accepts a projection or some kind of `FindOptions` as a parameter.